# How to overload a c++ member function in lua code

Tags: c++, lua, overloading

I want to write some lua code to over load a callback member function in c++, how can I do that? I use tolua++ as the glue library. Thank you for your response.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'm c++ programmer but a newbie of lua. Several days age I started to use cocos2d-x and write some logical codes in Lua. I wanted to draw lines on screen. According to the reference of cocos2d-x in c++, I should overload the "draw" function of a class derived from CCNode, and the I did something stupid like this:  
`local myScene = {}`  

`setmetatable(myScene, CCScene)`  

`function myScene:draw()`  

`....`  

`end`

Comment: It doesn't work. After that I tried to search the web and some documents, nothing found about that. So I posted the question, hoped someone more experienced could give me some sample codes, and then I can finish my task before the deadline.
Now, I've realized "Deriving a c++ class in lua" perhaps is impossibe, at least it isn't easy to implement. I think it should be better to change my direction: writing "myScene" in c++, and porting the new class to Lua.